# Chaning the order functions are loaded breaks the code unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that looks like this:

```
function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString) {
    $("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function() {
        // finds current cursor position
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        // this turns the textarea in a string
        var text = $(this).val();
        //only search for strings just typed
        var stringToSearch = text.substring(pos - searchString.length, pos);
        if (searchString == stringToSearch) {
            //if there is a match put the replaceString in the right place
            var newText = text.substring(0, pos - searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
            $(this).val(newText);
            //adjust the cursor position to the new text
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos, newpos);
        }
    });
}
autoCorrect("=>", '⇒');
autoCorrect("->", "→");
autoCorrect("+-", "±");
autoCorrect("<=", "≤");
autoCorrect(">=", "≥");
```

Now, I want to change it a little bit, I want to change the order the functions are running. Like this:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function() {
    function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString) {
        // finds current cursor position
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        // this turns the textarea in a string
        var text = $(this).val();
        //only search for strings just typed
        var stringToSearch = text.substring(pos - searchString.length, pos);
        if (searchString == stringToSearch) {
            //if there is a match put the replaceString in the right place
            var newText = text.substring(0, pos - searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
            $(this).val(newText);
            //adjust the cursor position to the new text
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos, newpos);
        }
    }
    autoCorrect("=>", '⇒');
    autoCorrect("->", "→");
    autoCorrect("+-", "±");
    autoCorrect("<=", "≤");
    autoCorrect(">=", "≥");
});
```

But this the script doesn't work anymore like this. I just don't understand why this breaks my code.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/4/

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is inside your function. Code design makes very little sense. No need to create a new function for every `keyup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new function creates a new scope :

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function () {
    autoCorrect("=>", '⇒', this);
    autoCorrect("->", "→", this);
    autoCorrect("+-", "±", this);
    autoCorrect("<=", "≤", this);
    autoCorrect(">=", "≥", this);
});

function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString, elem) {
    var acList = {
        "=>": '⇒',
        "->": "→",
        "+-": "±",
        "<=": "≤",
        ">=": "≥"
    },
        pos = elem.selectionStart,
        text = elem.value,
        stringToSearch = text.substring(pos - searchString.length, pos);

    if (searchString == stringToSearch) {
        var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
        elem.value = text.substring(0, pos - searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
        this.setSelectionRange(newpos, newpos);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/6/)

**EDIT:**

based on the comment asking if you could just pass an object of key / value pairs to be replaced together with the element, I cooked up this, which should work with just about any object you pass it :

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function () {
    var acList = {
        "=>": '⇒',
        "->": "→",
        "+-": "±",
        "<=": "≤",
        ">=": "≥"
    };
    autoCorrect(acList, this);
});

function autoCorrect(acList, elem) {
    var regstr = Object.keys(acList).join("|").replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$]/g, "\\$&"),
        reg    = new RegExp('('+ regstr +')', "gi"),
        pos    = elem.selectionStart,
        diff   = 0;

    elem.value = elem.value.replace(reg, function(x) {
        diff += x.length - acList[x].length;
        return acList[x];
    });

    elem.setSelectionRange(pos-diff, pos-diff);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/13/)

As a sidenote, this isn't really cross browser, as `selectionStart` and `setSelectionRange` doesn't work in all browsers, and neither does `Object.keys`, so depending on what browsers you need to support, you might have to polyfill those methods.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code as well haha. I'm still very new with this. I'm maybe asking too much, but I would like my code to look something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/7/ But this obviously not working, I just don't have the skils yet to let it look that way and still work.

Comment: That's harder, will need a second to test that fiddle out.

Comment: @90intuition - and there we go, posted a solution for that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I also got something to work magically. I thought I try the same thing I would do in python, and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/16/

Comment: That works as well, the only real issue being that it searches the same string five times, but you'll probably never notice that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the inner function, `$(this)` is not actually the jQuery object you're looking for. That's because `this` is set to the window object. Observe:

```
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    return this;
  }
  console.log(this, inner());
}

outer.call({ this: "is an object" });
```

This will log:

```
{ this: "is an object" }
[Object Window]
```

JS's scoping behavior is weird.
`this` is very magical and you can only really trust its value right at the place where it's set. Otherwise, it's probably `window`.

`.call` on a function calls the function with a `this` set to the first parameter, in this case `{ this: "is an object" }`. This is called "binding".
This is why in `outer`, `this` refers to our object. We say `outer` is bound to that object. In `inner`, we should distrust `this`, because it's not explicitly bound to anything -- so it's probably `window`.

Similarly to that example:

```
$('body').on('click', function clickCallback() {
  // `this` refers to the element that jQuery set it to,
  // as it called the `clickCallback` function with .call(element)
  $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#f00' });
  // We now have a bright red background!
  function changeColor() {
    // `this` refers to `window`!!!
    // We didn't bind it :(
    $(this).css({ color: '#0f0' });
    // Text color will not be changed!
  }
  changeColor();
});
```

Internally, jQuery uses the `.call` method to call the `clickCallback`, to bind the callback's `this` to the element that was clicked. So we're facing the exact same situation as with our `outer` and `inner` functions.

The solution to your problem is to either 1) Bind the inner function to the outer `this` or 2) Save the outer `this` for use in the inner function.

Usually you want to go for the latter. For the first, you'd need to either `.call` your function all the time (`autoCorrect.call(this, "=>", '⇒');`), which is ugly, or use `.bind` once (`autoCorrect = autoCorrect.bind(this);`), but that is not cool either, because not all browsers support the `.bind` method on functions, and it looks slower.

In your case, going for the latter option:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function() {
    // Store `this` for use in the inner function
    var self = this;
    function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString) {
        // `self` will now be the element we're looking for!
        // finds current cursor position
        var pos = $(self).prop("selectionStart");
        // this turns the textarea in a string
        var text = $(self).val();
        // [...]
    }
    autoCorrect("=>", '⇒');
    autoCorrect("->", "→");
    autoCorrect("+-", "±");
    autoCorrect("<=", "≤");
    autoCorrect(">=", "≥");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val()
        .replace(/=>/g, "⇒")
        .replace(/=>/g, "⇒")
        .replace(/->/g, "→")
        .replace(/\+-/g, "±")
        .replace(/<=/g, "≥")
        .replace(/>=/g, "≥"));
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/10/)</kbd>

Comment: But the cursor position goes to the end now. If you edit something in the middle.